# Problem installing PCTV triplestick 292e

Tags: kernel, mythbuntu, mythtv, firmware, dvb-t

I'm running Mythbuntu 14.04.

I've had two PCTV 290 usb tuners working just fine for a while in the same box. I had to replace one recently and ended up with a 292e. The 292e is supported in kernel 3.16, and requires firmware. so:

1 - I installed kernel 13.16.0-30-generic from packages found in aptitude.  The new kernel boots up fine and the old 290 tuner is working.

2 - I downloaded (from github) the firmware file dvb-demod-si2168-02.fw and copied it to /lib/firmware.  This is consistent with using the correct driver.

The result in syslog is that the new 292 tuner is recognised apparently correctly and then I get:

```
si2168 11-0064: si2168: found a 'Silicon Labs Si2168' in cold state
si2168 11-0064: si2168: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-demod-si2168-02.fw'
si2168 11-0064: si2168: found a 'Silicon Labs Si2168' in warm state
si2168 11-0064: si2168: found a 'Silicon Labs Si2168' in cold state
si2168 11-0064: si2168: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-demod-si2168-02.fw'
si2168 11-0064: si2168: found a 'Silicon Labs Si2168' in warm state
si2168 11-0064: si2168: found a 'Silicon Labs Si2168' in cold state
si2168 11-0064: si2168: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-demod-si2168-02.fw'
si2168 11-0064: si2168: found a 'Silicon Labs Si2168' in warm state
```

Note that the device has been correctly recognised and is loading the correct firmware.

I'm guessing, but doing it three times is not a good sign.

If I ask for a channel scan on the 292 I get the above messages ad infinitum.

Plus, from MythTV, I get this, over and over again:

```
mythbackend: message repeated 5 times: [ mythbackend[1893]: E SignalMonitor recorders/dvbchannel.cpp:1026 (GetSignalStrength) DVBChan[17](/dev/dvb/adapter1/frontend0): Getting Frontend signal strength failed.#012#011#011#011eno: Operation not supported (95)]
```

The 292 device appears as a new dvb adaptor but is not usable by MythTV.  I am following instructions from many sources.  Or maybe I'm not.  Lots of other people say it works, but not, apparently, for me.

I am at a loss for what to do next - does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an out of date version of MythTV, for which I can only apologise.

It turns out that was assuming that the error messages were a function of the driver but, by installing the latest version of MythTV 0.27 the messages went away and MythTV was able to scan for channels.

One learning point - Use a scanner such as dvbv5-scan to confirm that the hardware and driver are or are not working.  I did this when I built the system in the first place, but forgot all about it.

One other point to note - the driver appears to load the firmware when the device has been inactive for a while.  The mass messaging about downloading firmware was presumably because MythTV was failing to get the device started properly.  I still get some of these messages, but not nearly as many as I first reported.

I'm sorry to have put something up with such an obviously trivial answer, but thanks to those who looked at the question and gave it some thought.